# Inverse of the African proverb "The axe forgets; the tree remembers"

Tags: metaphors

There is an african proverb that says "The axe forgets; the tree remembers", meaning the person who hurt another forgets but the person who gets hurt remembers.

Is there an inverse to this? As in, the person who helps another forgets but the person who is helped remembers.

Comment: Since there is not, to my knowledge, an English equivalent of "The axe forgets; the tree remembers", still less its opposite, I don't believe that this is a question about the English language but rather about the African language in which the proverb exists.

Comment: I've seen adverts for charities saying something like a donation is one day's spending/sacrifice for you but can be a lifetime benefit for the recipient. Not sure if there's a metaphor attached to this, but it at least suggests that the idea might be found somewhere around charity fundraising.

Comment: *A dog is for life, not just for Christmas*? *Marry in haste, repent at leisure*? Or even just ***Time heals all***, if the key point is that *the passage of time* has implications for the truth or desirability of many things.

Comment: There's a quote by Kim Bryant: "Nobody forgets an act of kindness." But this hasn't achieved 'proverb' usage-level. There's also the recommendation "[When] doing acts of charity, do not let your left hand know what your right hand is doing" [[Berean Literal Bible; BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/matthew/6-3.htm)] from the Sermon on the Mount  (Matthew 6:3).